# How do I fix this click function to move to a particular location slowly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick

Code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function()) {
    $('a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({'scrollTop' : $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top}
    , 100000);
    return false;
})
});
```

On click the script is supposed to slowly move the location on the page.  For some reason it's not working at all.  I am new to JS so not sure what I am missing.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you include jQuery ?

Comment: Another possible issue is a mismatch between your anchor tags' href attributes and the elements you're trying to scroll to. Can you paste in your HTML, as well?

Comment: `100` Second?? isn't a log time to animate your scroll to top?

Comment: @maverick i did that just to see if it would work or not.

Comment: @adeneo yes i did.  i updated my question with the link that i am using.

Comment: What does `$(this).attr('href')` look like?

Comment: Open up your browser console, OP. Any errors?

Comment: You have an extra `)` in your code that produces an error. Change `.ready(function()) {` to `.ready(function() {`.

Comment: ^^^syntax error - http://jsfiddle.net/8cj7C/9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the extraneous `)` following the function parentheses (which, incidentally, closes the `ready` method inappropriately), causing a syntax error, there's an omitted semi-color following the parenthesis on the line below the `return false` statement (and yes, semi-colons are optional, but it's still a good idea not to rely on the automagical feature of JavaScript to guess where the line ends). Incidentally, I'd suggest a slight change:

```
//                           V- removed the extra ')'
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function () {
        /* caching the element you want to scroll
           to (using 'getAttribute()', rather than invoking jQuery,
           to retrieve the 'href' attribute, though still wrapping into
           a jQuery object to make use of the methods */
        var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
        $('html, body').animate({
            'scrollTop': target.offset().top
        }, 10000);
        return false;
    }); // <-- added the semi-colon
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/erGMa/1/).

Answer (score 2):

you have syntax error

```
$(document).ready(function() {//<<< here where having an extra `)`
    $('a').click(function(){
    var a = $(this).offset().top;// please replace `this` with the selector of the element you want to scroll to
    $('html, body').animate({'scrollTop' : a}// set the correct offset
    , 100000);
    return false;
})
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  The script actually doesn't do what it's supposed to do.  It doesn't take me to the location at all.  It just moves a little bit down but not to the location.  I guess I am doing something else wrong there.

Comment: In what way did it 'work', then? And the reason it doesn't go where you want it to go is because `a` is a variable containing the offset of the element that you clicked, not the offset of the element you want to scroll to (assuming you want to scroll to the element whose `id` is contained in the `href` of the clicked `a` element?